# Angular disable button if variables are empty

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

```
<button
    [disabled]="doSummary=== '' && selectedLOB === '' && adsList === ''"
    class="lmn-btn lmn-btn-primary"
    aria-label="Update"
    (click)="updateSelectedScopes()"
  >
  Update
</button>
```

I've an usecase where I need to disable the button if all 3 variables are EMPTY `''` and if any of the variable is not empty, button shouldn't be disabled. Currently I tried this way also variables are empty but its not disabling the button, not sure what's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming you initialized your variables to empty string.

So you can either create your variables like this

```
doSummary: string = '';
```

Instead of

```
doSummary: string;
```

Or you can check for something like this

```html
<button
    [disabled]="!doSummary && !selectedLOB && !adsList"
    class="lmn-btn lmn-btn-primary"
    aria-label="Update"
    (click)="updateSelectedScopes()"
  >
  Update
</button>
```

Comment: `!doSummay` include `doSumary===''` (really !doSumary is equivalent to doSummary=='' || doSummary===undefined || doSummary===null || doSummary===0) so it's enougth:`[disabled]="!doSummary && !selectedLOB && !adsList"`